# Rxjava of onBack double pressed to finish the activity

Tags: android, rx-java2

I want to implement a rxjava way of onback double press

So, I refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44196568/7653476) since it seems reasonable but it does not work
It show a toast and exit

My code implementation for observe the double back is:

```
private static final long EXIT_TIMEOUT = 2000;
private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
private PublishSubject<Boolean> backButtonClickSource = PublishSubject.create();

@NonNull
private Disposable observeBackButton() {
    return backButtonClickSource
            .debounce(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext(__ -> ToastUtils.showShort(R.string.back_more_toast_message))
            .timeInterval(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .skip(1)
            .filter(interval -> interval.time() < EXIT_TIMEOUT)
            .subscribe(__ -> model.finishActivity());

}
```

and for `onBackPressed`:

```
   public void onBackPressed() {
    backButtonClickSource.onNext(true);
}
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: When you call observeBackButton()?

Comment: I mean, when you do observeBackButton()? I've created a sample and it's working for me...

Comment: at the `onCreate` method of the activity

Comment: Weird... Try to paste my code and let me know if it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that OP had is that his `onBackPressed()` method was like this :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   super.onBackPressed();
   backButtonClickSource.onNext(true);
}
```

So, the trick is to remove the `super.onBackPressed()` so you can adapt that action to your needs.

I've created a sample and it's working for me, I've just deleted your model stuff and your `Toast` method, this is how it looks:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final long EXIT_TIMEOUT = 2000;
    private PublishSubject<Boolean> backButtonClickSource = PublishSubject.create();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        observeBackButton();
    }

    @NonNull
    private Disposable observeBackButton() {
        return backButtonClickSource
                .debounce(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(__ -> Toast.makeText(this, "Press once again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
                .timeInterval(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .skip(1)
                .filter(interval -> interval.time() < EXIT_TIMEOUT)
                .subscribe(__ -> MainActivity.this.finish());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        backButtonClickSource.onNext(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved my day thank you. when pasting your code I have noticed that I called super.onBackPressed() in the activity and this is what cause the problem.

Comment: I thought the same, then I came back to the question and you did not call the super.onBackPressed(); so that's why I didn't know what's happening... Make sure you post the same code as your AS next time

Comment: I pasted the presenter code and forget to paste the activity code

Answer (score 1):

How about this code?

```
private Disposable backPressedDisposable;
private BehaviorSubject<Long> backPressedSubject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0L); // init with 0

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 backPressedDisposable = backPressedSubject
   .buffer(2, 1)
   .map(it -> new Pair<>(it.get(0), it.get(1)))
   .map(pair -> pair.second - pair.first < TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2)) // 2 second
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(willFinish -> {
     if (willFinish) {
       finish();
     }
     else {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "press once more will exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
   });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 backPressedSubject.onNext(System.currentTimeMillis()); // add current time
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
 super.onDestroy();

 try {
   backPressedDisposable.dispose();
 } catch (Exception ignore) {}
}
```